# lesscss-maven-plugin not generating Source map?

Tags: maven, less

I am currently using lesscss-maven-plugin by org.codehaus.mojo;
the build is ok, and it is compiling properly.
How ever I am not generating any source map:

on my pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>lesscss-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-beta-3</version>
    <configuration>
        <force>true</force>
        <lessJs>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/lessjs/less.1.7.5-min.js</lessJs>
        <sourceDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/</sourceDirectory>
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-LESS</outputDirectory>
        <compress>true</compress>
        <includes>
            <include>r/assets/bootstrap.less</include>
            <include>r/assets/page.less</include>
        </includes>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>

        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

on the less.js I added this at the top:

```
less: {
    env: "development",
    "development": {
        options: {
            compress: true,
            yuicompress: true,
            optimization: 2,
            sourceMap: true,
            sourceMapFilename: "r/css/styles.map"

        },
        files: {
            "r/css/bootstrap.css": "r/assets/bootstrap.less",
            "r/css/page.css": "r/assets/page.less",
        }
    }
}
```

Did I forgot something? TIA.

Comment: Source map generation feature is not included with the browser version of the Less compiler (i.e. the `less.js` script you're using). Additionally, `sourceMap` option also has no effect if the integrated compression library is enabled (Though note that `yuicompress` flag in your config has no effect too. First of all `yuicompress` is deprecated in favor of `clean-css` and then again `clean-css` is not available in the `less.js` version of the compiler. Simply because `less.js` is primarily meant for client-side usage and CSS minifying does not make any sense there).

Comment: So regardless if i use the `less.js` or not it wouldn't generate a source map? Or should i search for a non browser version like grunt? All though i am not sure how to use grunt on  lesscss-maven-plugin. Or let along it would work....

Comment: Yes, for source maps you need any `node` based version of compiler. So  if there's no such tool/plugin available for the `maven` you're out of luck.

Comment: thanks guys.. will check on other solution... any node base compiler you guys might suggest?

Comment: There's the only actually, the official reference implementation: http://lesscss.org/#using-less (the same library is used in the corresponding Grunt an Gulp plugins if you're about to use these tools).